# Blade mixed with PHP doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Here's what I'm attempting to do (my code):

```html
@extends('base')
@section('title', 'Quests')
@stop
@section('main')

<? $quests = array (  
    1 => array ( "name" => "Quest 1", "level" => 100, "description" => "Write your description here", "reward" => "Shield, Boots"), 
    2 => array ( "name" => "Quest 2", "level" => 100, "description" => "4 Peoples needed!", "reward" => "Sword, Stonecutter Axe, Armor, Present(choose 1)"), 
    3 => array ( "name" => "Inferno Quest", "level" => 100, "description" => "Very hard quest. You need a big team to do this quest, the quest is long too!", "reward" => "bla bla") 
); 

?>

<div id="spaceholder">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="doc-content-box">
        <legend>Quests</legend>
        <p>The quests listed below are not all the quests on the server, there are many many other quests, but these are the ones with experience bonus. The expeirence bonus rewarded from quests is multiplied with your current experience stage.</p>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quest</th>
                    <th style="width: 70%">Notes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <? foreach($quests as $quest)
                echo '<tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong>' . $quest['name'] . '</strong><br>
                        <span class="label label-success">Experience bonus: 100 000</span><br>
                        <span class="label label-important">Level requirement: 35</span><br>
                    </td>
                    <td>This quest requires completing all missions.</td>
                </tr>';
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@stop
```

The output is like this:

1. First the arrays of the quest are displayed like a plain text (code)
2. The quest name is displayed also as a plain text (code)

If there is anyway of doing this with Laravel, I would like to know.

Comment: The name of your view file should ends with: `.blade.php` to makes Blade template works within Laravel.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo it is.. it's named quests.blade.php

Comment: when you said that your array is displayed as plain text, how it looks?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo http://3.imgland.net/jS-GL.png

Comment: did you configure to use short code for php? what happens when you use `<?php ?>` instead of `<??>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `<?` and `?>` , use `<?php` and `?>`, That made me suffer back in my CodeIgniter days.

I'd also prefer using the foreach loop the blade way.

```
@extends('base')
@section('title', 'Quests')
@stop
@section('main')

<?php
$quests = array (  
    1 => array ( "name" => "Quest 1", "level" => 100, "description" => "Write your description here", "reward" => "Shield, Boots"), 
    2 => array ( "name" => "Quest 2", "level" => 100, "description" => "4 Peoples needed!", "reward" => "Sword, Stonecutter Axe, Armor, Present(choose 1)"), 
    3 => array ( "name" => "Inferno Quest", "level" => 100, "description" => "Very hard quest. You need a big team to do this quest, the quest is long too!", "reward" => "bla bla") 
); 

?>

<div id="spaceholder">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="doc-content-box">
        <legend>Quests</legend>
        <p>The quests listed below are not all the quests on the server, there are many many other quests, but these are the ones with experience bonus. The expeirence bonus rewarded from quests is multiplied with your current experience stage.</p>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quest</th>
                    <th style="width: 70%">Notes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($quests as $quest)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <strong>{{$quest['name']}}</strong><br>
                            <span class="label label-success">Experience bonus: 100 000</span><br>
                            <span class="label label-important">Level requirement: 35</span><br>
                        </td>
                        <td>This quest requires completing all missions.</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@stop
```

I'm using a similar method on my project, it works a treat.